Minhag Oberland Selling Chametz
Does anyone by any chance know if the oberlander minhag is to sell chametz or not? Thank you very much

If it proves anything, in almost all my old Hungarian haggadot there's a contract template to sell chametz.

@Kazi the question remains what level of need justified using such a contract
